# django multiplicacioes dentro de un for

Tags: python, django

Buenas que tal estoy armando una vista en un formulario llenando desde la base de datos ahora se me presenta que debo multiplicar dos valores que estoy mostrando no se si es posible hacerlo desde la vista:
aca el codigo

```
                    {% for i in productos %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{i.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.descripcion}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.codigo}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.costo}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.precio}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.cantidad}}</td>
                
                   
                    <td>{{i.updated}}</td>
                    {% if i.imagen %}
                    <td><img src="{{i.imagen.url}}" alt="Error" width="100"  height="100"></td>
                    {% else %}
                    <td></td>
                    {% endif %}
                    

                    <td>
                        <button onclick="editarProducto('{{i.id}}',  '{{i.descripcion}}', '{{i.costo}}', '{{i.precio}}', '{{i.cantidad}}',  '{{i.imagen}}',)" class="btn btn-dark-outline btn-sm" data-toggle="modal"
                            href="#EditarPersonalModal"><img src="{% static 'index/img/editar.png' %}" alt="Error"
                                width="30"></button>
                        <button onclick="eliminarProducto('{{i.id}}')" class="btn btn-dark-outline btn-sm"
                            data-toggle="modal" href="#EliminarPersonalModal"><img
                                src="{% static 'index/img/delete.png' %}" alt="Error" width="30"></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

la idea es multiplicar la cantidad con el precio y mostralo en una variable para que se muestre en el formulario.
No se si es posible hacerlo en la vista gracias cualquier ayuda sera bienvenida.

Answer (score 0):

¿Te refieres a algo como esto?

```
<td>{{ i.precio* i.cantidad}}</td>
```

Si es asi podrias hacer algo como:

```
{% for i in productos %}
    {% set resultado = i.cantidad * i.precio %}
{% endfor %}
```

Y luego lo podrias mostrar en el html la variable

```
<h1>El resultado de la multiplicación es: {{ resultado }}</h1>
```

Luego con respecto a agregarlo a un formulario seria:

```
<form>
    <label for="resultado">Resultado:</label>
    <input type="text" id="resultado" name="resultado" value="{{ resultado }}">
</form>
```

Espero sea lo que estas buscando, Saludos.